# why use malloc function in c when we can declare arrays using arr[size] ,taking input from the user for size?

Tags: c, malloc

why use malloc function when we can write the code in c like this :

```
int size;
printf("please the size of the array\n");
scanf("%d",&size);
int arr[size];
```

this eliminates the possibility of assigning garbage value to array size and is also taking the size of the array at run time ...

so why use dynamic memory allocation at all when it can be done like this ?

Comment: Because the array might be too large for a local variable to fit on the stack typically implemented in C. And because VLAs are not always implemented.

Comment: also VLAs didn't used to be part of the standard,, although I think they're ~20 yrs old at this point. You may also want to use that memory outside of the current scope.

Comment: @yano VLAs were in C99 but are "optional" in C11.

Comment: *"this eliminates the possibility of assigning garbage value to array size"* - No it doesn't. Especially if you don't check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: And because you cannot declare VLAs at file scope.  Also because you sometimes want to allocate memory with a lifetime extending beyond what a VLA provides -- for instance, if you want to return a pointer to it from the function that allocates it.

Comment: @WeatherVane Interesting ... didn't know that

Comment: You need to check the return value of `scanf`: `if (scanf("%d",&size) != 1) /* error */;`

Comment: There is also the nice fact that if `malloc` fails you have a chance to handle that error, and it will be portable. Anything related to VLA failure can only be very platform specific.

Comment: Thank you so much people for answering my question...living in a village in India its difficult to find people to help you on that kind of stuff....

Answer (score 3):

This notation

```
int arr[size];
```

means VLA - Variable-Length Array.

Standard way they are implemented is that they are allocated on stack.
What is wrong with it?
Stack is usually relatively small - on my linux box it is only 8MB.
So if you try to run following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAX_BUF=10000000;

int main()
{
    char buf[MAX_BUF];
    int idx;
    for( idx = 0 ; idx < MAX_BUF ; idx++ )
      buf[idx]=10;
}
```

it will end up with seg fault.

TL;DR version

PRO:
VLA are OK for small allocations. You don't have to worry about freeing memory when leaving scope.

AGAINST:
They are unsafe for big allocations. You can't tell what is safe size to allocate (say recursion).

Answer (score 2):

Besides the fact that VLA may encounter problems when their size is too large, there is a much more important thing with these: scope.

A VLA is allocated when the declaration is encountered and deallocated when the scope (the `{ ... }`) is left. This has advantages (no function call needed for both operations) and disadvantages (you can't return it from a function or allocate several objects).

`malloc` allocates dynamically, so the memory chunk persists after return from the function you happen to be in, you can allocated with `malloc` several times (e.g in a `for` loop) and you determine exactly when you deallocate (by a call to `free`).

Comment: Thank you Jens for answering ...great help

Answer (score 1):

Why to **not** use the following:

```
int size;
printf("please the size of the array\n");
scanf("%d",&size);
int arr[size];
```

1. Insufficient memory.  `int arr[size];` may exceed resources and this goes undetected. [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42936329/why-use-malloc-function-in-c-when-we-can-declare-arrays-using-arrsize-taking/42937664#comment72969726_42936329) Code can detect failure with a `NULL` check using `*alloc()`.

   ```
   int *arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * size);
   if (arr == NULL && size > 0) Handle_OutOfMemory();
   ```
2. `int arr[size];` does not allow for an array size of 0.  `malloc(sizeof *arr * 0);` is not a major problem.  It may return `NULL` or a pointer on success, yet that can easily be handled.
3. Note: For array sizes, type `size_t` is best which is some *unsigned integer* type - neither too narrow, nor too wide.  `int arr[size];` is UB if `size < 0`.   It is also a problem with `malloc(sizeof *arr * size)`.  An unqualified `size` is not a good idea with *variable length array* (VLA) nor `*alloc()`.
4. VLAs, required since C99 are only optionally supported in a compliant C11 compiler.

Answer (score 0):

What you write is indeed a possibility nowadays, but if you do that with g++ it will issue warnings (which is generally a bad thing).

Other thing is your arr[size] is stored at stack, while malloc stores data at heap giving you much more space.

With that is connected probably the main issue and that is, you can actually change size of your malloc'd arrays with realloc or free and another malloc. Your array is there for the whole stay and you cannot even free it at some point to save space.

Comment: gcc allows VLA since an eternity. You only have to chose the suitable C standard on the command line.

Comment: it now seems I was completely wrong about gcc, I just get a warning and only because I have to use the older one as g++ and VLA is forbidden by iso c++